# Fetch Credit Card Details via NFC. dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The task is to fetch credit card(s) information via NFC and auto-fill the form fields i.e

- Card Number
- CVC
- Card Expiry

I did find below two packages (nfc_manager, flutter_nfc_kit) but still, it provides the bytes of information from which I can't fetch the desired information. Example Below:

```
{
  "isodep": {
    "identifier": [XX, XXX, XXX, XX],
    "hiLayerResponse": null,
    "historicalBytes": [
      XXX, XX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XX, X, XXX, X, XXX, X, XXX, X
    ],
    "isExtendedLengthApduSupported": true,
    "maxTransceiveLength": XXXXX,
    "timeout": XXX
  },
  "nfca": {
    "identifier": [XX, XXX, XXX, XX],
    "atqa": [x, x],
    "maxTransceiveLength": XXX,
    "sak": XX,
    "timeout": XXX
  }
}
```

If there is any guidance on how to play with those bytes Tags and stuff, or can provide a package or support to do this.

Below link is the reference of the desired task
Library for Android, which can read the data from a credit card.
Here it is: https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment
It's actually the source code for this application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.devnied.emvnfccard

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello did you get any solution ?

Comment: could you fetch data correctly ?